# IE11のエンタープライズモードではFileAPIが使えない？

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

作ったJavaのWebアプリケーションをIE11のエンタープライズモードで処理を実行させたのですが処理が動いてくれません。エンタープライズモードでなければ問題なく動いてくれます。
調査した結果JavascriptのFile APIを使っている処理のところで処理が止まっている形です。原因としてはエンタープライズモードに設定するとIE8対応モードになり、IE10から使えるFile APIは使えないからなのでしょうか。教えて下さい。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=file%20api) によると、IE8でFile APIはサポートされてないようです。質問者さんも書いておられるようにエンタープライズモードでは動作しないと考えて妥当ではないかと思います。